# HTML, Javascript: Append a new element to the current empty element

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check if an element has a content (except whitespaces) then append a new element if the element has no content? Just pure javascript if possible.

```
<div id="container">


</div>
```

if the container has only whitespaces then:

```
<div id="container">EMPTY</div>
```

VS

```
<div id="container">I am not empty</div>
```

if the container has content (no need to append EMPTY):

```
<div id="container">I am not empty</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to check for emptiness

```
var isEmpty = !document.getElementById("container").innerText.trim();
```

how to append

```
if(isEmpty) document.getElementById("container").innerText = "EMPTY";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if the `trim`med `innerHTML` is the empty string:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  if (div.innerHTML.trim() === '') div.textContent = 'Empty';
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<div>


</div>

<div>I am not empty</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```js
var checkDivs = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('#container').forEach((el)=>{
    el.innerText = (el.innerText) ? el.innerText:'EMPTY';
  })
}
checkDivs();
```

```html
<div id="container">


</div>
if the container has only whitespaces then:
<div id="container">EMPTY</div>

VS

<div id="container">I am not empty</div>
if the container has content (no need to append EMPTY):
<div id="container">I am not empty</div>
```